# Passing current value and another value from ajax page to javascript function

Tags: php

I am trying to pass 2 values to a javascript function. I have a recursive function as follows:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol class="dirlist">';
    $i=0;
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            $newdir= $dir.'/'.$ff;
            $newpaths=explode('/',$dir);
            $sliced = array_slice($newpaths, 0, -2); 
            //$string = implode("/", $sliced).'/'; 
            $string=implode("/", $dir).$ff; 
            echo '<li id="'.$ff.$i.'"><span><img src="/modules/fb/folder-icon.png" width="10" height="10"></img></span><a href="javascript:;" onclick="expand(this)">'.$ff.'</a>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" id="hiddenDir" value="'.$dir.'"';

            echo '</li>';   
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
```

And a javascript function

```
Function expand(val,i)
{


}
```

Within this javascript function I need to get the value `$i` passed from the php page.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
onclick="expand(\'$ff\',$i)"
```

Now complete line of code will be

```
echo '<li id="'.$ff.$i.'"><span><img src="/modules/fb/folder-icon.png" width="10" height="10"></img></span><a href="javascript:;" onclick="expand(\'$ff\',$i)">'.$ff.'</a>';
```